# openssl version gives multiple results

Tags: linux, openssl

I have installed the latest openssl version from source to /usr/local/stow/openssl-1.0.2d and managed with stow to have it available in /usr/local. This works fine

```
# /usr/local/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
```

However, when I don't give the absolute path to the executable, I get a different output:

```
# which openssl
/usr/local/bin/openssl
# openssl version
openssl: /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by openssl)
openssl: /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by openssl)
openssl: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by openssl)
openssl: /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by openssl)
OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013 (Library: OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015)
```

which is the exact same output as when I call `/usr/bin/openssl version`, the packages version on that OS.
However, when I set the PATH to use the binary under the stow directory directly, I get the same output as with the absolute path.

Anyone capable of explaining what goes on here?

Comment: Would you mind sharing more details?  OS version, other installed versions of openssl, did you upgrade the existing installation in /usr/local and did you remove the old libraries?  What was YOUR LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH set to when you built it?